# Can Cruncher crunch Daz models?

Tags: unity

I have a number of Daz 3D models that I would like to use in my Unity shooter game. The only problem seemed to be the high poly count of the Daz models.

However, I just came across the Cruncher Polyreduction tool (http://assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/4294). Is it possible to use this plugin to incorporate Daz models in my game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the file extension will be compatible with unity itself, the cruncher should work with no problems. Export it as one of unity-compatible extensions .FBX .OBJ etc. :)

Here is  the list of all supported file extensions.
http://unity3d.com/unity/workflow/asset-workflow

The only problem you may encounter is that if the ammount of vertices is beyond 64k~ then the unity will not let you import that asset. You will have to split it into a few models so that it has less vertices than aprox. 64,000. Of course, unless the cap has been made higher.

Comment: Well, then there's a problem; because Daz models generally consist of hundreds of thousands of polygons.

Comment: Well, you definately will not be able to crunch it inside of unity, unless you can import it to unity. You could turn it into less objects, and then import it into unity. Merge it together and create one new prefab. What models do you have? If they are full rigs with bones and everything then it might be problematic to divide those meshes.

Comment: Yes, they are full rigs. What should I do now?

Comment: Crunch it inside an external program, you might have a problem to divide it into a few meshes without taking out the rig apart, you take away any mesh part thats not bound to the rig. Or just get rid off the rig and set up a new one inside unity. My personal idea would be to downgrade the meshes to make them below 60k vert. each.  Otherwise the game will lag anyway, the cruncher is a good way to do LOD but usually it is done outside unity. Do you use 3ds max/Maya? Do you need high resolution models? Do you know how to split them into a few models?

Comment: I have used Maya. Can do basic modeling and stuff. No experience with animation, rigging, UV mapping, retopologising, etc. And no, I cannot split character models into multiple models.


I don't need high resolution models. I just want them to have the minimum polycount that's necessary for them to look decent in my third person shooter game.

Comment: In Maya go to the Polygon menu then you should see a 'Reduce' option with a box that opens a sub-menu with a set of extra options to give you advanced control over what you reduce (i.e preserve hard edges etc) Check it out or buy polygon cruncher for Maya for €120 http://www.mootools.com/plugins/us/commun/register.aspx